# Conditional isolate in shiny / check whether value changed

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here is the problem: I have a reactive input returning a string. One part of the string describes the category, one part the item. There are some events which I wish to trigger only if the category changes, but not when the item changes. In other words, I wish to conditionally isolate an event, such that a reactive function is called depending on the actual value of that event.

Here is a demonstration:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
         fluidRow(
                  selectInput("selection", "Select:", 
                              choices=c("catA:itemA", "catA:itemB", "catB:itemC"))),
         fluidRow("Category:", textOutput("category")),
         fluidRow("Item:",     textOutput("item"))

      )

server <- function(input, output) {

  .cat  <- reactive({ gsub(":.*", "", input$selection) })
  .item <- reactive({ gsub(".*:", "", input$selection) })

  output$category <- renderText({
    ## this should not be triggered when category does not change!
    message("Triggered category change")
    .cat()
  })

  output$item <- renderText({
    message("Triggered item change")
    .item()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code above does not do what I want it to do. What I want is that the `output$category <- renderText({...})` is triggered *if and only if* the value of `.cat()` changes. How can I achieve that modest goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reactive value instead of a reactive conductor:

```
  .cat <- reactiveVal()
  .item <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input[["selection"]], { 
    .cat(gsub(":.*", "", input$selection))
    .item(gsub(".*:", "", input$selection))
  })
```